# Show "add another answer" if there's already two answers

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, answers

Currently, the "add another answer" button only appears if you've already answered the question. How about putting it on if there's already two answers? This would *help* fend off people who register just to put a "thank you" or a "me too" answer as comment.

Comment: Why the downvote? Perfectly good feature request.

Comment: Welcome to Meta Stack Overflow. On Meta, downvotes just mean "I don't want this" instead of "this is a bad question". See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-work) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Why would "Add Another Answer" deter those posts when "Post Your Answer" doesn't? I don't think it would change anything; "another answer" just reminds you that you've already answered

Comment: Add Another Answer shows a dialog asking you if you're sure; Post Your Answer doesn't.

Comment: @Hello So your actual request is to have "Post Your Answer" show a dialog asking if you're sure, if there are answers already on the question?

Comment: Er, yeah, I guess.